# React Native build failed in android, Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-picker/android/build.gradle' line: 25

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, build.gradle, node-modules

*I'm encountering an issue while building an APK for my React Native project, specifically with the react-native-picker library. The error message I'm facing is:*

````
    Error:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * Where:
    Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-picker/android/build.gradle' line: 25
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-picker'.
    > Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
    
    *I've attempted to resolve this error by updating the compile method to implementation in the build.gradle file of the react-native-picker library, but the issue persists. Below is the relevant portion of the build.gradle file:*
    
    dependencies ```{
        if (isNewArchitectureEnabled() && getReactNativeMinorVersion() < 71) {
            implementation project(':react-native-picker') 
        } else {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        }
        implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  
    }```
    
    
    I've also made sure to adjust other parts of the script to comply with the latest Gradle versions, including updating the classpath in the buildscript block.
    
    *Build.gradle file:
````

The error indicates a problem with the `compile()` method in the `react-native-picker` library's `build.gradle` file, specifically on line 25. Despite attempting to replace `compile` with `implementation`, the issue persists. It seems related to dependency handling in Gradle, possibly caused by compatibility issues with the current Gradle version. Further investigation into the specific requirements of the library and potential conflicts with Gradle versions may be necessary for resolution.*

````
    ```buildscript {
        ext.safeExtGet = {prop, fallback ->
            rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
        }
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0")
        }
    }
    
    def getExtOrDefault(name) {
      return rootProject.ext.has(name) ? rootProject.ext.get(name) : project.properties['ReactNativePicker_' + name]
    }
    
    def getExtOrIntegerDefault(name) {
      return rootProject.ext.has(name) ? rootProject.ext.get(name) : (project.properties['ReactNativePicker_' + name]).toInteger()
    }
    
    
    def resolveReactNativeDirectory() {
        def reactNativeLocation = safeExtGet("REACT_NATIVE_NODE_MODULES_DIR", null)
        if (reactNativeLocation != null) {
            return file(reactNativeLocation)
        }
    
        // monorepo workaround
        // react-native can be hoisted or in project's own node_modules
        def reactNativeFromProjectNodeModules = file("${rootProject.projectDir}/../node_modules/react-native")
        if (reactNativeFromProjectNodeModules.exists()) {
            return reactNativeFromProjectNodeModules
        }
    
        def reactNativeFromNodeModulesWithPicker = file("${projectDir}/../../react-native")
        if (reactNativeFromNodeModulesWithPicker.exists()) {
            return reactNativeFromNodeModulesWithPicker
        }
    
        throw new Exception(
                "[react-native-picker] Unable to resolve react-native location in " +
                        "node_modules. You should add project extension property (in app/build.gradle) " +
                        "`REACT_NATIVE_NODE_MODULES_DIR` with path to react-native."
        )
    }
    
    def getReactNativeMinorVersion() {
        def REACT_NATIVE_DIR = resolveReactNativeDirectory()
    
        def reactProperties = new Properties()
        file("$REACT_NATIVE_DIR/ReactAndroid/gradle.properties").withInputStream { reactProperties.load(it) }
    
        def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = reactProperties.getProperty("VERSION_NAME")
        def REACT_NATIVE_MINOR_VERSION = REACT_NATIVE_VERSION.startsWith("0.0.0-") ? 1000 : REACT_NATIVE_VERSION.split("\\.")[1].toInteger()
    
        return REACT_NATIVE_MINOR_VERSION
    }
    
    def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
        // To opt-in for the New Architecture, you can either:
        // - Set `newArchEnabled` to true inside the `gradle.properties` file
        // - Invoke gradle with `-newArchEnabled=true`
        // - Set an environment variable `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_newArchEnabled=true`
        return project.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && project.newArchEnabled == "true"
    }
    
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    
    if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
        apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
    }
    
    android {
        def agpVersion = com.android.Version.ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION
      if (agpVersion.tokenize('.')[0].toInteger() >= 7) {
        namespace "com.reactnativecommunity.picker"
      }
    
      compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', 31)
    
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', 21)
            targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('targetSdkVersion', 31)
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary=getExtOrDefault('vector_drawable_use_support_library')
            buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString())
        }
    
        sourceSets.main {
            java {
                if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
                    srcDirs += [
                        "src/fabric/java",
                    ]
                } else {
                    srcDirs += [
                        "src/paper/java",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    repositories {
      maven {
          // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
          url "$projectDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
      }
      google()
      mavenCentral()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        if (isNewArchitectureEnabled() && getReactNativeMinorVersion() < 71) {
            implementation project(':react-native-picker') 
        } else {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  
        }
    } ```
    
    Despite these adjustments, the error persists. Could someone assist me in resolving this issue?
````